# Keycloak OIDC adapter support of JakartaEE

Tags: tomcat, keycloak, jakarta-migration

I am using KC OIDC adapter 22.0.5. It seems that it doesnt support JakartaEE. From the latest src, it still doesnt support JakartaEE.

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/adapters/oidc/tomcat/tomcat-core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/tomcat/OIDCCatalinaHttpFacade.java

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * @author <a href="mailto:bill@burkecentral.com">Bill Burke</a>
 * @version $Revision: 1 $
 */
public class OIDCCatalinaHttpFacade 
  extends CatalinaHttpFacade 
  implements OIDCHttpFacade
{
 [...]
}
```

Do you know if there any workaround?

I have tried to put java ee and jakarta ee api jar together. but I am still have the issue that

> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
> ... 37 more
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.servlet.ServletContext org.apache.catalina.Context.getServletContext()'
> at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.keycloakInit(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:111)
> at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.lifecycleEvent(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:70)
> at ...

Answer (score 1):

got an answer from keycloak team
https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-jakartaee-upgrade-still-refers-javax-package/23987

[image]